# Disconnecting from WiFi using python (Windows)

Tags: python, subprocess, wifi

I can connect to a WiFi network using:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(
    'netsh wlan connect {0}'.format(wifi_network),
    shell = True,
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE, 
    stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```

I was wondering if there was a similar way to disconnect from a WiFi network? Either disconnecting from all WiFi networks or disconnecting from a specific network (given a name) would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at **"netsh wlan disconnect"**: [Netsh Commands for Wireless Local Area Network](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755301(v=ws.10).aspx#bkmk_wlanDisConn)